# Simple inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $$2<\frac{x}{x-1}\leq3$$

What I did is:

$$2<\frac{x}{x-1}\leq3\Rightarrow 2<\frac{x-1+1}{x-1}\leq3 \Rightarrow 2<1+\frac{1}{x-1}\leq3\Rightarrow 1<\frac{1}{x-1}\leq 2\Rightarrow$$

$$1>x-1\geq \frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow 2>x\geq\frac{2}{3}$$

But the answer is $1<x\leq\frac{3}{2}$

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: You did well, the answer given by you in the last line may be wrong. Just try $x=1.1$ and you will see that it is not working!

Comment: it should be $2>x\ge \frac { 3 }{ 2 } $ in your last inequality

Comment: And, you may replace $\Rightarrow$ with $\iff$ in your answer. Of curse, after making the correction suggested by @Battani.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$3-\frac{x}{x-1}\geq 0$$ this is equivalent to $$\frac{2x-3}{x-1}\geq 0$$ and doing case work we get
$$x\geq \frac{3}{2}$$ or $$x<1$$ can you calculate the other inequality?

Comment: why the $-1$? what is the reason?

Comment: Are you sure? I think in this way, we get $x\geq 3/2$ or $x<1$.

Comment: sorry this was a typo!

Comment: No problem, I was in harry!!! I am sorry!

Comment: should i solve the left-side inequality?

Comment: I do not think so, because I guess when you finish, you would get the same answer as $3/2\leq x<2$ as the intersection of your answers.

Comment: @Majid but with the second inequality we get $x<1$ or $x\geq 2$

Comment: yes you have the conditions $$x\geq \frac{3}{2}$$ or $$x<1$$ and $$1<x<2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, so, the final solution in your way is $3/2\leq x<2$ as well. Nice.