# Help solving $1 < \frac{x + 3}{x - 2} < 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I worked a lot of inequalities here in MSE and that greatly helped me.
I've seen a similar inequality [here] [1], but the one I have today is significantly different, in that I'll end up with a division by 0, which is not possible.

[1] [[Simple inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832193/simple-inequality])

$$1 < \frac{x + 3}{x - 2} < 2$$
$$\implies 1 < \frac{x - 2 + 2 + 3}{x - 2}$$
$$\implies 1 < 1 + \frac{5}{x - 2} < 2$$
$$\implies 0 <  \frac{5}{x - 2} < 1$$
$$\implies 0 <  \frac{1}{x - 2} < \frac{1}{5}$$

I can't continue without falling into the division by 0. So my many thanks for your help.

Comment: Multiply by $x-2$ (which must be > 0 so it will not flip the signs) $0 < 1 <1/5 \cdot (x-2) \implies x > 7$.

Comment: Hint: x-2 must be greater than 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start. Right off the bat, we have to assume $x\neq 2$, otherwise the expression doesn't make sense.

For $0 < \frac{1}{x-2}$, we just need for the right term to be positive, i.e. for $x-2>0$, and so $x>2$.

For the next inequality, we can assume $x-2>0$ from the last part. Then we have $5 < x-2$ and so $x > 7$. Taking the intersection of $(2, \infty)$ and $(7, \infty)$, the latter set is our solution.

Answer (score 1):

The right inequality yields $x-2>5$ or $x>7$ (provided $x-2>0$; if not, the first inequality is not satisfied, and we can ignore this case). When the left inequality is reciprocated, $\frac10$ should be interpreted as $\infty$, so $\frac10=\infty>x-2$, which is true for *all* values of *x* and thus can be dropped. Hence the range of *x* values satisfying the inequality is $x>7$.

(Technically this operation is not exactly justified, but the range of values satisfying $\epsilon<\frac1x$ or $\frac1\epsilon>x$ increases to the right without bound as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.)

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{x-2} < \dfrac{1}{5}$ implies $5 < x-2$ iff $x- 2 > 0$.  If you proceed the cross-multiplication route, the case that $x - 2 < 0$ must also be considered.

Comment: Right, but if the other case is considered, the other inequality must fail because $\frac1{x-2}<0$. Have edited the answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac { 1 }{ x-2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 5 } <0\\ \frac { 5-x+2 }{ 5\left( x-2 \right)  } <0\\ \frac { 7-x }{ \left( x-2 \right)  } <0\\ \frac { \left( 7-x \right) \left( x-2 \right)  }{ { \left( x-2 \right)  }^{ 2 } } <0\\ \left( 7-x \right) \left( x-2 \right) <0\\ x\in \left( -\infty ;2 \right) \cup \left( 7;+\infty  \right) $$
on the other hand $0<\frac { 5 }{ x-2 } \Rightarrow x>2$ so the answer will be $$\left( -\infty ;2 \right) \cup \left( 7;+\infty  \right) \cap \left( 2;+\infty  \right) \Rightarrow \left( 7;+\infty  \right) \\ \\ $$

Answer (score 0):

Break it into two separate inequalities when you get to here:

$$ 0 < \frac{5}{x-2} < 1$$

First let's consider $0 < \dfrac{5}{x-2}$.  Since $5 > 0$, this inequality is satisfied when $x-2 > 0$, i.e., when $x > 2$.

Now let's consider $\dfrac{5}{x-2} < 1$.  Subtract $1$ from both sides and get a common denominator to get $$\dfrac{5}{x-2} - \dfrac{x-2}{x-2} < 0.$$

Combine and we have $$ \dfrac{5 - (x-2)}{x-2} < 0.$$

Simplify to get $$\frac{7-x}{x-2} < 0.$$

This inequality is satisfied when either of the following two conditions hold:

1. $7-x > 0$ **and** $x-2 < 0$
2. $7-x < 0$ **and** $x-2 > 0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: starting from $\frac{7-x}{x-2} < 0$, I get the solution $(-\infty, 2) V (7, \infty)$. Is this correct?

Comment: If by $V$ you mean union $\cup$, which you can get by typing $$ $\verb|\cup|$ $$ then yes.  That's the solution for $\dfrac{5}{x-2} < 1$.  There's one last step that needs to be done to get the final answer to the original problem.